# Laravel route not working for get request with parameters

Tags: php, laravel, routes

This is my url :

```
http://localhost:8000/password-reset?token=$2y$10$N8AX4N9XMhP4NKPCK6NtjOvwoOzeWmaQnOJkxrKg4Ul7shNhp0zdu
```

This is how my route looks like:

```
Route::get('password-reset?token={token}', 'Auth\PasswordResetController@index');
```

However this is not getting captured in the controller.

Comment: You don't need to put the token in the url. You can use `request()` to get it in your controller.

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei can you show an example please. Are you telling not to pass the token in get ?

Comment: Change the route first part to `password-reset` (remove `?token={token}`) and then in controller use `request('token')` to get the token value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the route first part to `password-reset` (remove `?token={token}`) and then in controller use `request('token')` to get the token value.